# Where can I find the "Film" Option in Blender 2.80?

Tags: eevee-render-engine

In the latest Blender 2.8 version I just realized that the Film look on color management is gone and everything is on filmic color management.

I haven't opened up Blender in a while so I don't really see any difference for now, but it would be nice to at least know why it got removed.

Edit: okay, so nobody knows what I'm talking about.

I'm talking about this:

[image]

when i open up blender 2.8, this is all i get.

[image]

Comment: "Film" and "Filmic" color transforms are not the same. If you really want to use such option, you need to change the whole folder for color management. Rename the current directory, then copy and older version  (like 2.79 or earlier) of the color management folder and re-start blender. The folder you want is in BLENDER/bin/VERSIONNUMBER/datafiles/colormanagement

Answer (score 2):

You can find it in the Render Tab of the Properties panel.

[image: color management]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

What I ended up doing to get film options back (I use it a lot for my own work as I enjoy the stylistic look of it) is copy the colourmanagement folder from an earlier build that had it blender/2.8/datafiles/colourmanagement and replace it with the current version.